# AWS ubuntu SSL installed but not loading https or http

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, https, openssl

I've followed exactly this youtube video tutorial to install SSL at my AWS Ubuntu Apache2 server. Youtube URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m06TttS2ZAM

Ubuntu version:  Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Apache version:  Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

My domain name: pilefo.com
Here is the sites-enabled: 000-default.conf details:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
         ServerAdmin admin@pilefo.com
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html
         ServerName pilefo.com
         ServerAlias www.pilefo.com
         SSLEngine on
         SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/pilefo_com.crt
         SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/pilefo.com.key
         SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/pilefo_com.ca-bundle
          <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#Redirect all http traffic to https

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName pilefo.com
      ServerAlias www.pilefo.com
      Redirect permanent / https://www.pilefo.com
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf file details
link: https://textuploader.com/1avcv

Apache error log
https://textuploader.com/1avcn
https://textuploader.com/1avcn

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu version? Apache version? Add your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` files to your question.

Comment: All queries answer noted. Please help me

Comment: I cannot find anything wrong with your Apache configuration. Can you access your HTTP server via its IP address? Add your firewall rules to your question.

Comment: Looks like https://pilefo.com/ this working now but when I try www.pilefo.com it is not working at all: http://prntscr.com/mbdma4 and ping result: http://prntscr.com/mbdqhs

Comment: What is your DNS server entry for `www`? This entry should be a CNAME pointing to `pilefo.com`. Is `https://pilefo.com` or `https://www.pilefo.com` working?

Comment: I will bet that you configured your DNS server about two hours ago. It took a while for the DNS entries to go live and that is why `pilefo.com` started to work. Now you just need to fix your DNS server entry for `www.pilefo.com`.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnHanley for your help.

Comment: I am glad that you have everything working now.